# compare to lists and return the different indices and elements in python

Tags: python

I want to compare to lists and return the different indices and elements.

So I write the following code:

```
l1 = [1,1,1,1,1]
l2 = [1,2,1,1,3]

ind = []
diff = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] != l2[i]:
        ind.append(i)
        diff.append([l1[i], l2[i]])

print ind
print diff

# output: 
# [1, 4]
# [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

The code works, but are there any better ways to do that?

---

Update the Question:

I want to ask for another solutions, for example with the iterator, or ternary expression like `[a,b](expression)` (Not the easiest way like what I did. I want to exclude it.) Thanks very much for the patient! :)

Comment: If the code works, then post it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and not here!

Comment: Define "better" ways (faster, more readable, memory efficient, etc).

Comment: You can do something like `diff = [[v1, v2] for v1, v2 in zip(l1, l2) if v1 != v2]` but that doesn't give you the indices.

Comment: Hi @BhargavRao , I want to ask for another solutions, for example with the iterator, and ternary expression like [a,b](expression) (not the normal easiest way like what I did. I want to exclude it.)

Comment: @user5061 Hi, if it is possible, I want to know all the cases.

Comment: @xirururu "All" is too broad. Readable would be the exact opposite of oneliners you'll get if you ask for "pythonic" version of your code :P (here they come). Your code looks readable enough to me. To check speed, use [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#module-timeit).

Comment: @user5061 Thanks for the answer, readable code is sometimes also important than the short code. I will check the timeit module. I am new in python and very interested in the art of the python coding. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to output all the information in a single list.

```
>>> [[idx, (i,j)] for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if i != j]
[[1, (1, 2)], [4, (1, 3)]]
```

This will produce a list where each element is: `[index, (first value, second value)]` so all the information regarding a single difference is together.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is the following

```
>>> l1 = [1,1,1,1,1]
>>> l2 = [1,2,1,1,3]
>>> z = zip(l1,l2)
>>> ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(z) if x[0] != x[1]]
>>> ind
[1, 4]
>>> diff = [z[i] for i in ind]
>>> diff
[(1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

In Python3 you have to add a call to `list`  around `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try functional style:

```
res = filter(lambda (idx, x): x[0] != x[1], enumerate(zip(l1, l2)))
# [(1, (1, 2)), (4, (1, 3))]
```

to unzip `res` you can use:

```
 zip(*res)
 # [(1, 4), ((1, 2), (1, 3))]
```